# Function creating expression list

Tags: r, list, function, expression

I have this function:

`myexplist <- function(a,b,c,...) list(...)`

Trying to create nothing returned:

`myexplist(a=4, b=a**2, c=a**3)`

`list()`

my expected output would be:

```
$a
4
$b
a**2
$c
a**3
```

Could any one explain how to fix it?
Thanks

I tried to write a function to create expression list and nothing returned

Comment: Either return `a`, `b`, and `c` from your parameter list, or add them explicitly to the list you’re returning. At the moment you are not using them.

Comment: myexplist <- function(a,b,c,...) { 
list(...)
}

Comment: @user330 Tried but returns empty

Comment: Try now myexplist(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), will return a list with 4,5 and 6

Comment: @user330 please see my expected output in updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you can do

```r
myexplist <- function(a,b,c,...) as.list(match.call())[-1]
```

For example:

```r
myexplist(a=4, b=a**2, c=a**3)
#> $a
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> $b
#> a^2
#> 
#> $c
#> a^3
```

If you only want certain arguments included, you can do:

```r
myexplist <- function(a,b,c,...){
  mc <-  as.list(match.call())
  list(b = mc[["b"]], c = mc[["c"]])
}

myexplist(a=4, b=a**2, c=a**3)
#> $b
#> a^2
#> 
#> $c
#> a^3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and if I only want to capture specific arguments or want to modify the argument list how to modify the function?

Comment: @SALAR this captures all the arguments, whatever they are. If you want to remove some named arguments from the list you can filter the list according to its names. you want using the names of the list. e.g. `function(a, b, c, ...) { res <- as.list(match.call())[-1]; res[names(res) %in% c("a", "b")]}` should return only the arguments a and b for example.

Comment: Sorry, when trying without argument `c` it returns this error:
`Error in c("a", "b") : argument "c" is missing, with no default`. And with argument `c` returns this error:
`Error in names(res) %in% c("a", "b") :  argument "c" is missing, with no default`.
Is there any thing I have missed or could you please check the function? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
myexplist <- function(...) {
  rlang::enexprs(...)
}
  myexplist(a=4, b=a**2, c=a**3)
```

further q :
Thanks for the answer, and if I only want to capture specific arguments or want to modify the argument list how to modify the function?

```
myexplist <- function(...) {
 enx <- rlang::enexprs(...)
 purrr::keep_at(enx,c("b","c"))
}
myexplist(a=4, b=a**2, c=a**3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and if I only want to capture specific arguments or want to modify the argument list how to modify the function?